# Recover all the account under Mnemonic using ethers.js

Tags: wallets, ethers.js, mnemonic

I am new using ethers.js

```
const { Wallet } = require('ethers');
const wallet = Wallet.fromMnemonic('one two three four ...');
```

I want to use that code to recover all the accounts from that *Mnemonic*. Maybe it is something that I do not understand quite well but it is just retrieving the first account for that *Mnemonic*.

How do I recover all the accounts?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `Wallet.fromMnemonic` function has a second argument to specify the BIP-32 derivation path. By default it will use `m/44'/60'/0'/0/0`, but if you want to get the second account, you can use `m/44'/60'/0'/0/1` for example:

```
const { Wallet } = require('ethers');
const wallet = Wallet.fromMnemonic('one two three four ...', `m/44'/60'/0'/0/1`);
```

Alternatively, you can use the `HDNode` class to quickly derive child keys from a mnemonic phrase. For example:

```
const { utils } = require('ethers');
const hdNode = utils.HDNode.fromMnemonic('one two three four ...');

const secondAccount = hdNode.derivePath(`m/44'/60'/0'/0/1`); // This returns a new HDNode
const thirdAccount = hdNode.derivePath(`m/44'/60'/0'/0/2`);
```

The `HDNode` can also be used to get an instance of `Wallet`. This is also what `Wallet.fromMnemonic` does.

```
const wallet = new Wallet(hdNode);
```

Answer (score 3):

In the newer ethers version, this is slightly changed.

```
const { ethers }  = require('ethers');

const mnemonic = "one two three four .....";
const hdNode = ethers.HDNodeWallet.fromPhrase(mnemonic);

const secondAccount = hdNode.derivePath(`m/44'/60'/0'/0/1`);
const thirdAccount = hdNode.derivePath(`m/44'/60'/0'/0/2`);

console.log(secondAccount.address);
console.log(thirdAccount.address);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're struggling to recover all accounts created by **Metamask**, here is the solution (ethers.js v6):

```
const ethers = require("ethers");

const phrase = "YOUR_PHRASE";

const mnemonic = ethers.Mnemonic.fromPhrase(phrase);

for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
    const wallet = ethers.HDNodeWallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic, `m/44'/60'/0'/0/${index}`);
    console.log(wallet.address);
}
```